Number of data movements for a read() from an SSD drive in Linux
My question concerns the internal kernel operations involved in a read system call. How does the Linux kernel handle a read system call, specifically in terms of data movement from SSD storage to user-space buffers? So, suppose that I have a 500MB file stored on an SSD drive, called test. Consider a simple code like the following:
int buf_size = 1024*1024*500;
char* buffer = malloc(buf_size);
int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
read(fd, buffer, buf_size);

My question is: How many times is the data of the file moved within a Linux system? My answer is three times. First, the SSD moves the data to a DMA buffer. Then, the device driver transfers the data from the DMA buffer to a kernel buffer. Finally, the kernel moves the data from the kernel buffer to the user-space buffer. Is this correct?

I am not sure what you mean by a DMA buffer. The SSD may well make a copy of the data in internal RAM, this might be your buffer. It is possible that the kernel buffer and the user space buffer are the same and no copy is involved, but that will not happen for your simple program.

If I’m not mistaken, with network interface cards (NICs), there are DMA-able buffers where the NIC transfers incoming packets via DMA. The NIC then raises an interrupt. The device driver copies the data to kernel memory to free up the DMA-able buffer for future packets. Later, the kernel copies the data to user-space memory. I’m wondering if this is also how the NVMe device driver works.

Typically a NIC card will be programmed to write directly to memory, and then will raise the interrupt, there is no copy by the device driver. The DMA-able memory is a part of the kernel memory.
